# How to pass a function callback to a class member?

Tags: c++, templates, function, callback, pass-by-reference

I'm templatizing a queue class so I can use it with anything from ints to whatever structs I need to define.

I need to pass a comparison function to the class constructor, a predefined comparison function for ints and alike then leave it up to the client to provide any comparison functions they may want. But how do I do this?

```
template<typename Type>
int cmpFn(Type one, Type two)
{
    if (one < two) return -1;
    if (one > two) return 1;
    return 0;
}

template <typename Type>
class Queue
{
    public:
        Queue()
        {
            Type *list = new Type[size];
            // What do I do now?
            // How to define this constructor?
            // It must pass a comparison function
            // to a private sort method in this class.
        }
    private:
        void sortFunc(Type list, int(fn)(Type one, Type  two)=cmpFn);
};
```

There's probably some mistakes in the above code since I just wrote it down from the top of my head to make my question more clear. But all I'm interested in is how to pass a comparison function to a sort method when defining a class.

This is a personal exercise, I'm not enrolled in any course nor have I access to any tutors. I've been googling this for a while now, but I couldn't come up with the right answer... I guess I wasn't asking the right question to Mr. Google.

P.S.
The client may want to provide comparison functions for any sort of data, like:

```
struct individual
{
    string name;
    int age;
    double height;
};
```

I guess that the constructor has to be like this:

```
Queue(int (*fn)(Type, Type) = cmpFn);
```

But how do I define/implement this? It's not a Queue object itself who will use this callback function, but its method: sort();

Comment: This isn't an answer, but in the Spirit of C++ I would design this differently; namely, expect `T` to come with an `operator<` or a specialization of `std::less<T>`, and use that for sorting. Maybe even expose iterators, though that may not help for a queue-like structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working, compilable example of what I think you want:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Type>
int cmpFn(Type one, Type two)
{
    if (one < two) return -1;
    if (one > two) return 1;
    return 0;
}

template <typename Type>
class Queue
{
    public:
        // This is the typedef for your callback type
        typedef int (*callback)(Type one, Type two);

        Queue(Type *list, size_t size, callback func = cmpFn)
        {
            sortFunc(list, size, func); // works too
        }

    private:
        void sortFunc(Type *list, size_t size, callback func) {
            for (size_t i=0; i<size; i++) {
                for (size_t j=0; j<size; j++) {
                    if (i == j) continue;

                    int val = (*func)(list[i], list[j]);
                    switch (val) {
                        case 1:
                            std::cout << list[i] << " is greater than " << list[j] << "\n";
                            break;
                        case -1:
                            std::cout << list[j] << " is greater than " << list[i] << "\n";
                            break;
                        case 0:
                            std::cout << list[i] << " and " << list[j] << " are equal\n";
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

};

int stringCmp(std::string one, std::string two) {
    if (one.size() < two.size()) return -1;
    if (one.size() > two.size()) return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    // compare ints, use generic comparison function (cmpFn)
    int myInts[2] = {1, 2};
    Queue<int> qi(myInts, 2);

    // compare strings, use our own comparison function (stringCmp)
    std::string myStrings[2] = {"foo", "bar"};
    Queue<std::string> qs(myStrings, 2, stringCmp);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling and executing the program above should give you this output:

```
2 is greater than 1
2 is greater than 1
foo and bar are equal
bar and foo are equal
```

Basically what it does:

- The `Queue` constructor accepts a `list` array, its size and a callback function.
- If the callback function is not provided, it uses the generic one (`cmpFn`).
- It then calls `sortFunc` which loops though all the elements in the `list` array and compare them using the callback function.

In the code above, you have an example with `int` and `std::string`.

Comment: Thank you! That's almost what I need. Now I only need to figure up how to store the callback function reference in the class object. Conversely, I don't want the sortFunc to be automatically called by the constructor, instead the client will be calling it when needed in the fashion myqueue.sortFunc(); or myqueue->sortFunc(); The client does state which comparison function for sorting use when constructing the object: Queue<int> myqueue(cmpFuncStrings);

Comment: @user971191: For that you'll have to make `sortFunc` public (it was private so I assumed you wouldn't). If you want to store the callback, `callback` is defined as a type, so just declare a member of that type and define it in the constructor.

Comment: I had it all behind my eyes all the time... thank you for pointing it out! :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
void sortFunc(Type list, int(*fn)(Type one, Type  two) = cmpFn<Type>);
```

Probably best to pass the arguments by const-reference rather than by copy. Who knows if they're even going to be copyable?

Comment: Thanks for replying, but how do I make this class store the comparison function provided by the client? The client will provide how to compare the elements contained in the list. I only define the standard comparison function myself. I'm really lost on this.

Comment: Ah, I get it. You could make the comparison function a template paramter of your class, and then add a corresponding constructor argument. Take a look at how `set` is implemented (or at least check out its public interface).

Comment: @user971191: And if you don't want it to be part of the template arguments, you will have to do some type erasure.